# Java - How can I difference between two or more JButtons?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm actually doing a project and I have a `ArrayList` of `JButtons` with an `ActionListener` added. And I don't know how to difference between them in my `ActionPerformed` method. The buttons have all the same title but any button do the same action.

Comment: Surely the buttons are declared differently; `JButton button1 = new JButton(); JButton button2 = new JButton();` Then `if (event.getSource().equals(button1)) {`

Comment: `yourEvent.getSource()` - this will tell you exactly which component triggered the event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your actionPerformed method do something like this :

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    if(e.getSource() == jButton1){
      //perform action when jButton1 clicked
    }
    if(e.getSource() == jButton2){
      //perform action when jButton2 clicked
    }
//So on and so forth
}
```

Comment: I just realised I've always used `.equals()` for `JButton`s.